# How to increment the number by setinterval in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular8

Tried to increment the number upto 10 after reached 10 again will start same like this : http://jsfiddle.net/dRMrL/
I tried by typescript but not working. How to do it?

```
count:number=0;
ngOnInit(){ 
  setInterval(this.myCount,500); 
}

myCount() {

  if (this.count > 10) {
          this.count = 0;
    }
   console.log("Count form 0 to 10"+this.count);  
    this.count ++; 

}
```

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kma3tn?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Just convert myCount function as Fat arrow from normal function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a closure over the `counter` and the `max` number.

Inside of the function increment `counter`, take an output and adjust `counter` with `max` value.

```js
const count = (max, counter = 0) => () => {
        console.log(counter);
        counter = counter === max ? 0 : counter + 1;
    };

setInterval(count(10), 500);
```

Without a closure, but with a global variable.

```js
var counter = 0;

setInterval(() => {
    console.log(counter);
    counter = counter === 10 ? 0 : counter + 1;
}, 500);
```

Comment: It is not starting from 0

Comment: You have any other method without closure.

Answer (score 1):

The `this` keyword in your `myCount` refers the the `setInterval` function. You can solve this by using an [arrow function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in your `setInterval` and call your `myCount` method inside the arrow function.

This way the `this` keyword inside `myCount` refers to your component.

```
ngOnInit(){ 
  setInterval(() => {
    this.myCount();
  }, 500);
}

myCount() {

  if (this.count > 10) {
        this.count = 0;
  }
  console.log("Count form 0 to 10 - " + this.count);  
  this.count ++; 

}
```

Comment: Not working: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m7kpsi?file=src/app/app.component.ts